# Word(s) describing person in "Elephant has tail, elephant has trunk" scenario

Tags: single-word-requests

> A survey shows there is a shortage of women who are software developers. Sarah replies to it saying the  reason is because   women feel intimidated by the men to women ratio  in the workplace.
>
> John replies saying a reason for the shortage could be that women generally prefer roles where they interact with other people as well as they prefer a work-life balance.
>
> Sarah tells John he is statement is incorrect, he doesn't know what he is talking about and she is correct.

Both Sarah and John are correct
How would you  with a single/ two words describe her or  her stance of only believing/focus on one answer, her answer, when there are multiple answers.

Another example:

> Pete says an elephant has a trunk. Dave says an elephant has tusks. Pete says Dave is incorrect but he is correct. Both are correct. Which single/ two words would convey that Pete's view is correct but at the same time incorrect by discounting Dave's view.

Comment: to me "self-righteous" reads your views are right over someone else's view. I'm looking for a "onewaythinking" word(s) but correct as their view is correct as well as the other person's view is correct. He is   stubborn for only believing one answer.

Comment: Pete is right. Not all elephants have tusks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a case of [fallacy of the single cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_single_cause) or some other logical fallacy.

*fallacy of the single cause*

> Dictionary Definition:-
>   The fallacy of the single cause, also known as complex cause, causal oversimplification, causal reductionism, and reduction fallacy,[1] is a fallacy of questionable cause that occurs when it is assumed that there is a single, simple cause of an outcome when in reality it may have been caused by a number of only jointly sufficient causes.

Comment: Welcome!  Your suggestion of *fallacy of the single cause* seems absolutely right, but it would be helpful to include an explanation in your answer of what it means, to show readers why it is apt.  You can edit your answer to add that.

Comment: Thank you! ^^ Perhaps I should have commented rather than answered; I wanted to be brief.

Comment: Thanks your link is perfect and contains the synonyms I need  complex cause, causal oversimplification, causal reductionism, and reduction fallacy

Answer (score 2):

The posted scenarios are examples of people with a [blinkered outlook](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blinkered). This implies that their perception of the world is highly constrained by their prejudices and limited world view.

The facts that a person with a blinkered outlook recognises are usually true but, because they refuse to recognise other facts and world views, their interpretation of those facts is often very wide of the mark.

The phrase is a metaphor taken from the idea of a horse having 'blinkers' fitted so that it can only see ahead to reduce the chances of its becoming startled and bolting.

Comment: Just what I wanted to say! +1.